# How is the keras accuracy showed in progress bar calculated? From which inputs is it calculated? How to replicate it?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to understand what is the accuracy "**acc**" shown in the keras progress bar at the end of epoch:

> 13/13 [==============================] - 0s 76us/step - loss: 0.7100 - **acc**: 0.4615

At the end of an epoch it should be the accuracy of the model predictions of all training samples. However when the model is evaluated on the same training samples, the actual accuracy can be very different.

Below is adapted example of [MLP for binary classification from keras webpage](https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/). A simple sequential neural net is doing binary classification of randomly generated numbers. The batch size is the same as the number of training examples (13), so that every epoch contain only one step. Since loss is set to `binary_crossentropy`, for the accuracy calculation is used `binary_accuracy` defined in [metrics.py](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/ed07472bc5fc985982db355135d37059a1f887a9/keras/metrics.py#L26). `MyEval` class defines callback, which is called at the end of each epoch. It uses two ways of calculating the accuracy of the training data a) model evaluate and b) model predict to get prediction and then almost the same code as is used in keras `binary_accuracy` function. These two accuracies are consistent, but most of the time are different to the one in the progress bar. Why they are different? Is is possible to calculate the same accuracy as is in the progress bar? Or have I made a mistake in my assumptions?

```py
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from keras import callbacks

np.random.seed(1) # fix random seed for reproducibility 
# Generate dummy data
x_train = np.random.random((13, 20))
y_train = np.random.randint(2, size=(13, 1))

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(64, input_dim=20, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

class MyEval(callbacks.Callback):
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        my_accuracy_1 = self.model.evaluate(x_train, y_train, verbose=0)[1]
        y_pred = self.model.predict(x_train)
        my_accuracy_2 = np.mean(np.equal(y_train, np.round(y_pred)))
        print("my accuracy 1: {}".format(my_accuracy_1))
        print("my accuracy 2: {}".format(my_accuracy_2))

my_eval = MyEval()

model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          epochs=5,
          batch_size=13,
          callbacks=[my_eval],
          shuffle=False)
```

The output of the above code:

```
13/13 [==============================] - 0s 25ms/step - loss: 0.7303 - acc: 0.5385
my accuracy 1: 0.5384615659713745
my accuracy 2: 0.5384615384615384
Epoch 2/5
13/13 [==============================] - 0s 95us/step - loss: 0.7412 - acc: 0.4615
my accuracy 1: 0.9230769276618958
my accuracy 2: 0.9230769230769231
Epoch 3/5
13/13 [==============================] - 0s 77us/step - loss: 0.7324 - acc: 0.3846
my accuracy 1: 0.9230769276618958
my accuracy 2: 0.9230769230769231
Epoch 4/5
13/13 [==============================] - 0s 72us/step - loss: 0.6543 - acc: 0.5385
my accuracy 1: 0.9230769276618958
my accuracy 2: 0.9230769230769231
Epoch 5/5
13/13 [==============================] - 0s 76us/step - loss: 0.6459 - acc: 0.6923
my accuracy 1: 0.8461538553237915
my accuracy 2: 0.8461538461538461
```

using: Python 3.5.2, tensorflow-gpu==1.14.0 Keras==2.2.4 numpy==1.15.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it has to do with the usage of `Dropout`. Dropout is only enabled during training, but not during evaluation or prediction. Hence the discrepancy of the accuracies during training and evaluation/prediction.

Moreover, the training accuracy that is displayed in the bar shows the averaged accuracy over the training epoch, averaged over the batch accuracies calculated after each batch. Keep in mind that the model parameters are tuned after each batch, such that the accuracy shown in the bar at the end does not exactly match the accuracy of a valication after the epoch is finished (because the training accuracy is calculated with different model parameters per batch, and the validation accuracy is calculated with the same parameters for all batches).

This is your example, with more data (therefore more than one epoch), and without dropout:

```py
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from keras import callbacks

np.random.seed(1) # fix random seed for reproducibility 
# Generate dummy data
x_train = np.random.random((200, 20))
y_train = np.random.randint(2, size=(200, 1))

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(64, input_dim=20, activation='relu'))
# model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
# model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

class MyEval(callbacks.Callback):
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        my_accuracy_1 = self.model.evaluate(x_train, y_train, verbose=0)[1]
        y_pred = self.model.predict(x_train)
        my_accuracy_2 = np.mean(np.equal(y_train, np.round(y_pred)))
        print("my accuracy 1 after epoch {}: {}".format(epoch + 1,my_accuracy_1))
        print("my accuracy 2 after epoch {}: {}".format(epoch + 1,my_accuracy_2))


my_eval = MyEval()

model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          epochs=5,
          batch_size=13,
          callbacks=[my_eval],
          shuffle=False)
```

The output reads:

```
Train on 200 samples
Epoch 1/5
my accuracy 1 after epoch 1: 0.5450000166893005
my accuracy 2 after epoch 1: 0.545
200/200 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/sample - loss: 0.6978 - accuracy: 0.5350
Epoch 2/5
my accuracy 1 after epoch 2: 0.5600000023841858
my accuracy 2 after epoch 2: 0.56
200/200 [==============================] - 0s 383us/sample - loss: 0.6892 - accuracy: 0.5550
Epoch 3/5
my accuracy 1 after epoch 3: 0.5799999833106995
my accuracy 2 after epoch 3: 0.58
200/200 [==============================] - 0s 496us/sample - loss: 0.6844 - accuracy: 0.5800
Epoch 4/5
my accuracy 1 after epoch 4: 0.6000000238418579
my accuracy 2 after epoch 4: 0.6
200/200 [==============================] - 0s 364us/sample - loss: 0.6801 - accuracy: 0.6150
Epoch 5/5
my accuracy 1 after epoch 5: 0.6050000190734863
my accuracy 2 after epoch 5: 0.605
200/200 [==============================] - 0s 393us/sample - loss: 0.6756 - accuracy: 0.6200
```

The validation accuracy after the epoch pretty much resembles the averaged training accuracy at the end of the epoch now.

Comment: You are right, that the Dropout was not supposed to be there, thank you. Now after setting the `batch_size` to 200 (or putting back number of samples to 13), epoch=batch, we get the same accuracy as is in progress bar only that it is in the following line/epoch, which weird and maybe it has to do with printing.
```
Epoch 2/15
200/200 [==============================] - 0s 8us/step - loss: 0.6856 - acc: 0.5350
my accuracy 1 after epoch 2: 0.635
my accuracy 2 after epoch 2: 0.635
Epoch 3/15
200/200 [==============================] - 0s 5us/step - loss: 0.6789 - acc: 0.6350
```

Comment: Exactly, that's due to the printing. I added the epoch in the callback's printout to avoid the confusion.

Comment: Yes, the epoch number printing is helpful, but according to what I see in the output (and the small piece in my comment^^ if you formatted), it should be `epoch + 2` (not `epoch + 1`). (remember to set batch size to be the same as number of samples). Thank you! I accept it.